# How to check if an attached SSD device is SATA or PCIe on Linux?

Tags: linux, ssd, sata, pci-express

I have a machine with both SATA and PCIe SSDs attached. Is there a set of Linux commands (on Ubuntu or CentOS) that I can use to check if a given SSD is SATA or PCIe?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
lsblk -io NAME,TYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,MODEL
```

will identify all the block devices, i.e., drives. Then, run

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sd*X* | grep SATA
```

where X is each drive letter found. If the result contains SATA, well, it's the SATA drive.

Alternatively,

```
lspci
```

will identify all the PCI devices, including PCIe.

Or, you can look for the ***NVMe*** logo on the drive.

Comment: I have a M2 drive that I'm pretty sure is using PCIe (it's in the M2 slot on the mobo), but it says SATA all over the place on the second command.  I don't understand, I thought it was PCI.  There's also a sata controller listed in the lspci

Comment: Many M.2 SSDs simply have a SATA interface. This is most probaby the reason why your M.2 drive is displayed as a SATA device. M.2 SSDs with SATA interface are BTW not faster than regular SATA SSDs (I found out the hard way after I had bought an M.2 and thought it would be much faster than my regular SSD).